# Force CUDA toolkit version 11.6 in Ubuntu 18.04, latest in repos is 9.1

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, cuda

I just installed cuda following instructions in nvidia site:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu1804.pin
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu1804.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.6.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-6-local_11.6.0-510.39.01-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-6-local_11.6.0-510.39.01-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-6-local/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

I then installed nvidia-cuda-toolkit:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

All of this went without issues, but it installed the version 9.1 of the toolkit:

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

I need to have version 11.1 or later of the toolkit, but it seems 9.1 is the latest in the repos:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-cuda-toolkit is already the newest version (9.1.85-3ubuntu1).
```

How can I force the installation of the latest?

This are the details of my system:

```
$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

$ uname -m
x86_64

$ uname -r
4.15.0-167-generic
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are following [official guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#package-manager-metas), you follow it partially.

You have to install one of the following meta-packages:

> | Meta Package | Purpose |
> | --- | --- |
> | cuda | Installs all CUDA Toolkit and Driver packages. Handles upgrading to the next version of the cuda package when it's released. |
> | cuda-11-6 | Installs all CUDA Toolkit and Driver packages. Remains at version 11.6 until an additional version of CUDA is installed. |
> | cuda-toolkit-11-6 | Installs all CUDA Toolkit packages required to develop CUDA applications. Does not include the driver. |
> | cuda-tools-11-6 | Installs all CUDA command line and visual tools. |
> | cuda-runtime-11-6 | Installs all CUDA Toolkit packages required to run CUDA applications, as well as the Driver packages. |
> | cuda-compiler-11-6 | Installs all CUDA compiler packages. |
> | cuda-libraries-11-6 | Installs all runtime CUDA Library packages. |
> | cuda-libraries-dev-11-6 | Installs all development CUDA Library packages. |
> | cuda-drivers | Installs all Driver packages. Handles upgrading to the next version of the Driver packages when they're released. |

So the easiest way would be

```
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

to get latest CUDA 11.6 version fully installed. For example its compiler will be installed in this location:

> ```
> $ which nvcc 
> /usr/local/cuda-11.6/bin/nvcc
> ```

with needed 11.6 version

> ```
> $ nvcc --version
> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
> Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
> Built on Fri_Dec_17_18:16:03_PST_2021
> Cuda compilation tools, release 11.6, V11.6.55
> Build cuda_11.6.r11.6/compiler.30794723_0
> ```

Also you should know that `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` package came from [Ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nvidia-cuda-toolkit) as shown below

> ```
> $ apt-cache policy nvidia-cuda-toolkit 
> nvidia-cuda-toolkit:
>  Installed: (none)
>  Candidate: 9.1.85-3ubuntu1
>  Version table:
>     9.1.85-3ubuntu1 500
>        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse amd64 Packages
> ```

so you should not use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm a fool. I had installed cuda as you recommended, but I thought that was only the drivers and not the toolkit. Also, the reason nvcc comand wasn't working before I installed the nvidia-cuda-toolkit (already removed, thanks), is because the cuda bin wasn't in the path. All fixed now, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the environment variables - `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, this will work.

Example:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.6/bin/$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.6/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```